# Horizontal List is displaying in line

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a horizontal List sing html and css but when is displayed in the browser it seems to go down in steps rather than in a straight line,  any idea what might be causing this?

CSS

```
#nav li a {
display:block;
float:left;
text-indent: -9999px;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
background-image:url(images/buttons.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto auto;
margin-left:15px;
}

#nav li a:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}

#nav li.one a {
background-position: 0pt 0px;
}

#nav li.two a {
 background-position: 0pt -88px;
}

#nav li.three a {
background-position: 0pt -176px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">

<li class="one"><a href="#"><strong>One</strong> Selected Works on Display</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="#"><strong>Two</strong> Thoughts, Links, Inspiration &amp; Miscellany</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="#"><strong>Three</strong> Those Who Have &amp; Continue to Inspire</a>    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the `LI` tag, not the `A` tag.

```
#nav li a {
display:block;
float:left;     <--- move to LI
text-indent: -9999px;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
background-image:url(images/buttons.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto auto;
margin-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: floating won't maintain alignment when the div collapses down past the default size. You have to set the li alignment using the "display:inline-block" rule

Comment: People have been successfully making horizontal menus using floats long before "inline-block" was even invented.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the styles regarding display (e.g. display, float, width, height) to the li element instead of the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Awww...the infamous "try to horizontal-align a series of list items to get evenly sickpaced links in a nav bar" trick!

Try using the "inline-block" css argument like so:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {display:inline-block; //add margin and padding to make it look pretty}
```

That should be it. This is the same rule that [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is using for the links at the top of the nav bar.